# lua hello world file path error, trying to get 1st script to work

Tags: lua

[image: lua fail]

just trying to get my 1st lua script working.
Compiler can't seem to get past the C directory address, gives me a [C]: in? error, like it needs more code to figure out where the C drive is.

Can't find anything on the net about this.
Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The `[C]` in the error indicates the error occurred in a C function, as in the C programming language, not the Windows C drive.

Answer (score 0):

Change the direction of your slashes...

Instead of  `"C:/Users/James/..."`  use backslashes as path separators `"C:\\Users\\James\\..."`

Also, another option is for you to run your file directly from the terminal by using:

```
lua C:\Users\James\Documents\my_lua\test0.lua
```

Comment: tried double backslash, get 
" cannot open  C:\Users\James\Documents\my_lua\test0.lua: no such file or directory  stack traceback: [C]: in function 'dofile' stdin:1: in main chunk [C]: in ? "

Comment: @gristy - What about `lua C:\Users\James\Documents\my_lua\test0.lua` ?  Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

DOH !!! 
fell for one of the oldest tricks ever. can you spot it? its in the image. A simple exercise for any 1st semester college level programmer. man... and I've been programming on and off for 30 years. So rusty...

clue

> @gristy - What about lua C:\Users\James\Documents\my_lua\test0.lua ? Does it work?

nope

Comment: I have no idea.  What was the reason?

Comment: lul. goes to show experienced programmers fall for it from time to time, its not just me.
notepad appended the extension .txt to the filename so the filename was test0.lua.txt

Comment: Most programmers have [Hide extensions for known file types](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/865219/how-to-show-or-hide-file-name-extensions-in-windows-explorer) checkbox **un-checked**.  Only lazy ones have it turned on (it is checked by default). After un-checking you will see "test0.lua.txt - Notepad" in Notepad window caption.